# using custom Compound View as a Listview's item

Tags: android

**Problem:**

I've developed a custom compound view and I'm unsure of how to display it in my listview.

**What I've done:**

**-> My custom compound view**

```
public class HZScrollView extends LinearLayout {

public HZScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initView(context);
}

   private void initView(Context context) {

        mContext = context;

        setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                               ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        this.setLayoutParams(lp);

        //inflate XML resource and attach
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mInflater.inflate(R.layout.hz_scroll_view, this, true);
    }
}

public void addContent(String name, String age, String sex) {
//content is added to the individual widgets within this compound view
}
```

**-> My Adapter**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
if(convertView == null) {
convertView = new HZScrollView(context); //<--- PROBLEM !
}
}
```

The major problem I'm experiencing is that the line marked with "PROBLEM" causes the exception `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.app/.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: <merge /> can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true`

In sample code around the 'net, the getView() usually inflates an XML layout, but in my case the compound view is completely self-contained.

**Question:**

How is it possible to insert/attach my custom compound view into the listview item ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

1) in the adapter, assigning the HZScrollView to convertView is fine

2) to fix another problem with LayoutParams, the initView() needed to be updated to use AbsListView.LayoutParams instead of ViewGroup.LayoutParams (since the parent container is a listView)

3) to fix the InflateException, child views used `<merge>` in the XML, I refactored that to wrap the child views in LinearLayout's. Note: using `<merge>` in the XML for "hz_scroll_view" file is just fine.

---

The really interesting part, for me, was point #1 because I was unsure whether assigning a custom compound view to a listview item would work.

Comment: I am trying to use a custom compound view that gets inflated into a `TableLayout` in the view's java file it extends `LinearLayout` and the XML for it has `LinearLayout` as the root element. So I should change that to `merge`? I am getting a `InvalidStateException` or something like that. The `View` I am trying to add already has a parent or something like that is the message.